# How do I reference a Web API in another project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Many moons ago I wrote a .NET Web API. Now I want to reference it in a new project I'm working on and I can't remember how to do it properly. A quick link to some reference material would be greatly appreciated.

The new project is MVC 4(or 5) and the Web API application was developed in .NET framework 4.5.1. As the Web API application isn't running anywhere I can access from my dev box I'd like to reference the interfaces in my new application and use Dependency Injection to shove in the data while doing development.

*Irrelevant Note: The Web API application is a work of art. I did it back before the TBI set in. (Actually, I just forgot. It's been a year or two.) It's got 10 projects in it; Has dependency injection all over the place; Has unit tests for damn near everything; Has Interfaces for all public classes and methods; Uses Automapper, Entity Framework, Owin, and Ninject; There's an associated web project for configuration and troubleshooting. In short, I used to develop good stuff and now I'm at a hack level because I've been all over the place the past couple of years and have difficulty getting data to show up in a view.

*Side Note: The new application is getting data from two data sources. One is the Web API mentioned above that is getting data from a legacy data source and the other is from a FHIR data source. I going have to switch between the two on the fly. For example: User is on the West Coast so there data is coming from the FHIR data source. Users over the rest of the country will be getting data from the legacy data sources until they catch up with the left coast people.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is to deploy your web api and integrate it in your new project otherwise you can convert it into class library and use in your project. Please see the following article. I hope it helps you:
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceAnExistingNETFrameworkProjectInAnASPNETCore10WebApp.aspx